# JFrame Display - Mouse Listeners

Tags: java, swing, listeners

I am currently developing a game in java.When I start my game I get to chose between Full Screen and Window Mode, by clicking somewhere in the frame.The Window Mode works perfectly, but I have some issues at the full screen mode.So if I have in my main() just a simple initialization of the game, like `new FullscreenMode()`, the game works perfect, the listeners are working.In the code bellow if I launch the full screen Mode frame from the constructor it works perfect, but if I launch it from a function that belongs to my class, all the listeners won't work...And when I say it's not working properly, I mean the listeners are not responding, everywhere I click I get no response from the game, but if the full screen Mode Frame is launched from the constructor everything works perfectly.Thank you in advance!

```
 public class ResolutionChoser extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener,
        MouseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImageLoader loader;
    private BufferedImage rezImg = null;


    public ResolutionChoser() {
        super("Welcome!");
        requestFocus();
        loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
        rezImg = loader.loadImage("/RezImg.png");
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH * Game.SCALE + 2,
                Game.HEIGHT * Game.SCALE + 2));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH * Game.SCALE + 2,
                Game.HEIGHT * Game.SCALE + 2));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(Game.WIDTH * Game.SCALE + 2,
                Game.HEIGHT * Game.SCALE + 2));
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(rezImg, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        setContentPane(jl);

        //Works Perfectly if I do it like so
        // launchFullScreen();


    }

    //Method that launches my fullscreen game
    public void launchFullScreen() {
        removeMouseMotionListener(this);
        removeMouseListener(this);
        MultiBufferTest.main(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResolutionChoser rc = new ResolutionChoser();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("CLICKED AT: " + arg0.getX() + "--" + arg0.getY());
        launchFullScreen();
        //not working properly, the listeners for my game aren't responding

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are removing the listeners in your `launchFullScreen()` method:

```
public void launchFullScreen() {
    removeMouseMotionListener(this);
    removeMouseListener(this);
    MultiBufferTest.main(null);
}
```

How do you expect the listeners to respond?

Comment: I am removing the listeners from this JFrame.. the ResolutionChoser.MultiBufferTest.main(null); launches new JFrame, with other listeners, that are added there.And I am launching the same method(1 time works, in constructor, and in the mouseClicked method it isn't)

Comment: Well how would we know that? Maybe post the relevant code then?

Comment: @user3187893's question should be improved so that we don't have to guess what the code he's not showing us is doing. To the original poster, I suggest that you isolate your problem by creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Don't attach `Mouseistener`s directly to a frame, there is a `JRootPane` and content pane (and possibly a glass pane) between the frame the user, any one of theses could be stealing mouse events, which will prevent your frame from receiving mouse events.

Instead, attach the `MouseListener` to the top level component directly

Also...

```
JLabel jl = new JLabel() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(rezImg, 0, 0, null);
    }
};
```

this is not only a bad idea (you've broken the paint chain), it's also not required, as `JLabel` is capable of displaying images.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and 
[How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details